# How to find the highest value element in a list with reference to a dictionary on python

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I code a function in python which can:

- iterate through a list of word strings which may contain duplicate words and referencing to a dictionary,
- find the word with the highest absolute sum, and
- output it along with the corresponding absolute value.
- The function also has to ignore words which are not in the dictionary.

For example,
Assume the function is called `H_abs_W()`.
Given the following list and dict:

```
list_1 = ['apples','oranges','pears','apples'] 
Dict_1 = {'apples':5.23,'pears':-7.62}
```

Then calling the function as:

```
H_abs_W(list_1,Dict_1)
```

Should give the output:

> 'apples',10.46

EDIT:
I managed to do it in the end with the code below. Looking over the answers, turns out I could have done it in a shorter fashion, lol.

```
def H_abs_W(list_1,Dict_1):
    
    freqW = {}
    for char in list_1:
        if char in freqW:
            freqW[char] += 1
        else:
            freqW[char] = 1

    ASum_W = 0
    i_word = ''
    for a,b in freqW.items():
            x = 0
            d = Dict_1.get(a,0)
            x = abs(float(b)*float(d))
            if x > ASum_W:
                ASum_W = x
                i_word = a
       
    return(i_word,ASum_W)
```

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ['apples','oranges','pears','apples'] 
Dict_1 = {'apples':5.23,'pears':-7.62}

d = {k:0 for k in list_1}
for x in list_1:
    if x in Dict_1.keys():
        d[x]+=Dict_1[x]
        
m = max(Dict_1, key=Dict_1.get)
print(m,Dict_1[m])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
key, value = sorted(Dict_1.items(), key = lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)[0]

print(f"{key}, {list_1.count(key) * value}")

# apples, 10.46
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Counter` to calculate the frequency(number of occurrences) of each item in the list.

- `max(counter.values())` will give us the count of maximum occurring element
- `max(counter, key=counter.get)` will give the which item in the list is
  associated with that highest count.

========================================================================

```
from collections import Counter


def H_abs_W(list_1, Dict_1):
    counter = Counter(list_1)
    count = max(counter.values())
    item = max(counter, key=counter.get)
    return item, abs(count * Dict_1.get(item))
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how/why this solves the OP's issue. For long term value future visitors should be able to quietly see if your answer applies to their own coding issues, and learn how to apply it to their own use case. Highlight the main part of your solution that address OP's issue, and why it does so. Code only answers are frowned upon on SO. Remember SO is not a coding service. Not all questions should be answered, and they should include explanations for learning, and long term value, which is reflected in greater upvotes.